# set ImageView below a ScrollView

Tags: android, background

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
...
```

Can I place image as background in bottom Activity (window)? For instance, when scrolling ScrollView, image must be always bottom and visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `RelativeLayouts`? Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout android:width="fill_parent"  
android:height="fill_parent"
...>

  <WhateverYouWantAtBottom android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  /> 

  <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <whateverYouWantScrollable android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

At the bottom you could have an imageview with the image you wanted. No matter how long your content in the scrollview is, the imageview will not budge from the bottom as long as it has the alignParentBottom set as true.

EDIT: In the above code, the `<whateverYouWantAtTheBottom>` will be in the background as I declared it first. The foreground will be the contents of the scrollView as that was added last in the XML.

Comment: Nice, but this image on top. Can this below, for instance, ScrollView?

Comment: That's easy. Whatever you want in the background, declare that first in your XML code. For example if you want the scrollview to be above the ImageView, then first write your ImageView code and then your ScrollView code. Ill add that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and its work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/imageView1" >



    </ScrollView>



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But this way if your scrollview is full, even then it wont overlap your imageview. This way the image will always take the bottom part of the screen. The question asked for the image to be at the background, not as a separate section at the bottom.

Comment: thats exactly what he want :)